# Dragging and Dropping onto a scaled element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a div element that I want to be able to drag onto a scaled element. However when I do this, the div element doesn't go to the right coordinates of the element but it does when I drag it around for the second time.

I also think it scales up when the element get's added, which I want to try and avoid.

Can anyone help me fix this? (especially the whole no going to the right spot thing)

I've tried things like this to get the actual coordinates of the div but I'm not sure how to translate that over to the draggable element since `mousemove` doesn't work when I'm dragging something.

```
$("body").on("mousemove", ".formBackground", function(e){
    div_x = (e.offsetX != null) ? e.offsetX : e.originalEvent.layerX;
    div_y = (e.offsetY != null) ? e.offsetY : e.originalEvent.layerY; 

    console.log("x "+div_x+" y "+div_y); 
});
```

Here is my actual code and a link to my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n0qbmw03/1/)

### HTML

```
<div id="drag1" class="drag" style="font-size:12px;background-color:#E2F4FE;width:220px;padding:10px;color:#000;font-weight:normal;">New box</div>
<br />
<br />
<div id="formBox">
    <div id="formScale">
        <div class="formContent">
            <div class="formBackground" style="background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/roOQNaS.png');"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JS

```
var percent = 1.5;

$("#formScale").css({
    'transform': 'scale(' + percent + ')',
        '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + percent + ')',
        '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + percent + ')',
        '-ms-transform': 'scale(' + percent + ')'
});

var counter = 0;
//Make element draggable
$(".drag").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    containment: 'frame',
    //When first dragged
    stop: function (ev, ui) {
        var pos = $(ui.helper).offset();
        objName = "#clonediv" + counter
        $(objName).css({
            "left": pos.left,
                "top": pos.top
        });
        $(objName).removeClass("drag");
        //When an existiung object is dragged
        $(objName).draggable({
            containment: 'frame',
            stop: function (ev, ui) {
                var pos = $(ui.helper).offset();
                console.log($(this).attr("id"));
                console.log(pos.left)
                console.log(pos.top)
            }
        });
    }
});


$(".formBackground").droppable({
    drop: function (ev, ui) {
        if (ui.draggable.attr('id').search(/drag[0-9]/) != -1) {
            counter++;
            var element = $(ui.draggable).clone();
            element.addClass("tempclass");
            $(this).append(element);
            $(".tempclass").attr("id", "clonediv" + counter);
            $("#clonediv" + counter).removeClass("tempclass");
            //Get the dynamically item id
            draggedNumber = ui.draggable.attr('id').search(/drag([0-9])/)
            itemDragged = "dragged" + RegExp.$1
            console.log(itemDragged)
            $("#clonediv" + counter).addClass(itemDragged);
        }
    }
});
```

### CSS

```
#formBox {
    position:relative;
}
#formScale {
    border:1px solid red;
    position:relative;
    width:350px;
    height:200px;
    margin:0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.formContent {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.formBackground {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly, there are a number of things you need to take care of.

## 1. The relative position

When the parent of an HTML element changes (i.e. the element is appended to some other element), its position on the screen changes, unless it `position` property is `fixed` (which is not the default).
So when you append your `div` to `$('.formBackground')` (I'm just gonna call it `formBackground`), its position becomes relative to its previous sibling, or, if there is no previous sibling, to `formBackground` itself.
To work around this, you have to subtract the offset of `formBackground` from the offset of the draggable.
Additionally you need to set `position` to `absolute`, so the draggable is always rendered relative to `formBackground` instead of the previous draggable.

[The CSS `position` property is explained here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).

To do that, remove this passage (lines 19-22 in your fiddle):

```
$(objName).css({
    "left": pos.left,
        "top": pos.top
});
```

And instead add the following passage after `element.addClass("tempclass");` (currently line 43):

```
element.css({
    "position": "absolute",
    "left": ui.offset.left - $(this).offset().left,
    "top": ui.offset.top - $(this).offset().top
});
```

The next thing to take care of is:

## 2. The offset scaling

If now you would set `var percent = 1.0;` in line 1, the draggable should stay exactly where is it.
With any other factor however, it will not, since its offset is multiplied too.

[The CSS `transform` property and its `scale()` value are explained here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp), however the documentation does not mention that this applies to the offset of an object too, it just seems to be that way.

You can simply edit the snippet above to divide `left` and `top` by `percent`:

```
element.css({
    "position": "absolute",
    "left": (ui.offset.left - $(this).offset().left) / percent,
    "top": (ui.offset.top - $(this).offset().top) / percent
});
```

Now the upper left corner of the draggable should always stay where you drop it, regardless of what `percent` is set to.

I forked and edited your fiddle to reflect these two changes. Since I do not have 10 reputation yet, I cannot post more than 2 links, but here it is anyway: `http://jsfiddle.net/n7yns9eq/2/`

## 3. (Optional) The top-left-anchored transformation

I find it a bit more user-friendly to make the "point of reference" for elements their center instead of their upper left corner. It seems more intuitive to me. If you find that too, here's how to do it:

From `left`/`top` you have to subtract half of the amount by `width`/`height` will increase. In code:

```
element.css({
    "position": "absolute",
    "left": (ui.offset.left - $(this).offset().left - $(ui.draggable).width() * (percent - 1) / 2) / percent,
    "top": (ui.offset.top - $(this).offset().top - $(ui.draggable).height() * (percent - 1) / 2) / percent
});
```

Note that instead of `$(ui.draggable)` you **can not** use `element`, because `element` has not been rendered at this point and since it has no explicit value set for `height`, `element.height()` will return `0`.

Fiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/9xbgqdeo/1/`

## 4. Dead areas and non-proportional moving

Another problem I noticed was that now, if you drop a draggable in the lower of leftmost third of `formBackground`, the drop doesn't happen. I don't know if this is caused by the browser engine (not resizing the functional area of an object) or by jquery (disregarding transformations).
The only way I can think of to work around this is to make `body` droppable instead of `formBackground`, check if it is within the borders of `formBackground` and if yes, append it there, discard it otherwise.
Note that for this to work if your page does not fill the whole browser window, you'd have to set the following CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And don't forget to replace every `this` in the droppable function with `$('.formBackground')`.

In addition, when grabbing an existing draggable from `formBackground` and moving it around, it drifts away from the cursor, which I consider unwanted. To prevent this I suggest moving the div back to its original parent and reverting the offset changes that were made when it was dropped on `formBackground`.

I'm honestly too lazy to provide fiddles for those two changes now (edit: `http://jsfiddle.net/gtc17z6b/1/`), but I hope this solves your question anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much Siguza! This is incredibly helpful and explains a lot. I'm having a hard time understanding the last part about the cursor. I'm extremely interested in this last part. If you find some time and could make a fiddle, that would help me a lot and I'd award you the bounty right then and there. You deserve it with all the time you put in.

Comment: [Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/gtc17z6b/1/). Still has some of your debugging code, is inconsistent in use of strings, uses jquery internals, but works. A draggable is now considered "inside the box" if its center is inside the box. See lines 56 & 57 if you'd like to change that.

Answer (score 1):

I would have have a look at this library:

https://greensock.com/draggable

it does handle the scale and transfortmation the right way:

http://codepen.io/gavrochelegnou/pen/KpWVqo

easy like drinking a glass of water:

```
Draggable.create(".box", {type:"x,y", edgeResistance:0.65, bounds:".container", throwProps:true});
```